# Unable to pass url string when segue perform using AMSlideMenu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, amslidemenu

I am building an article reading app using storyboards.

I am also
using AMSlideMenu Library for the main menu. I am facing an problem  that is, i want to 
pass different url values when user click on different rows in AMSlideMenu.

here is my storyboad :
[image]

here is my code:

```
   -(NSString *)segueIdentifierForIndexPathInLeftMenu:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *idetifier = @"firstSegue";
 //   ysTableViewController *str;

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        urlString  = @"http://example.com/1";
        break;
    case 1:
                urlString  = @"http://example.com/2";
        break;
    case 2:
                     urlString  = @"http://example.com/3";
        break;
        default:
                     urlString  = @"http://example.com/4";
        break;

}

return idetifier;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"])
    {
        ysTableViewController *controller = (ysTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"asgasfg-----%@",urlString);
        controller.Mainlinks = urlString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got over the problem by using NSUserDefaults temporarily but still it not a proper solution. Still looking for a proper method to pass parameters b/w classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new UIViewController inside prepareForSegue method.

— YourTableViewController *newObj= [[YourTableViewController alloc]init];
 -  newObj.value=@"your value";

By This way u can pass your value.

Comment: the property is set and i have synthesis it the ysTableViewController.m but still i am getting the value as null

Comment: i am implemeting this and get back to you in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of `AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController` or `AMSlideMenuRightTableViewController` (if you don't have already), 
and implement following method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *destNC = segue.destinationViewController;
    UIViewController *destVC = nc.viewControllers.firstObject;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"])
    {
       FirstViewController *vc = (FirstViewController *)destVC;
       // pass your data to vc 
       // e.g.
       vc.title = @"I'm from first row";
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondSegue"]) {
       // same for others  
       //...
    }
}
```